# Console.Writeline stopped producing output when I merged two c# projects

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2012, project

I initially developed a simple GUI project for testing out a vendor's SDK.  I then added the vendor's SDK example as a second project that the GUI depended on.  After some changes I have the example code talking to hardware and working well.

At this point I tried to move the vendor code into the main project and then delete the SDK example project from my solution as it doesn't make sense to have it separate.  This compiles fine, but weirdly all of the hardware debug info I was printing via Console.Writeline stopped working.

Do I have to enable Writeline output somehow in the main project?  I'm new to c# and couldn't find anything searching.

Comment: GUI projects don't have a console.

Comment: Project + Properties, Debug tab, ensure that the hosting process option is still ticked.  If it is then odds are getting drastically lower.  Tick the unmanaged code debugging option or try SysInternals' DebugView utility.  Do ask the vendor for help.

Answer (score 2):

In your solution explorer, select the project, right click and go to Properties. Find where it says 'project output type' and switch it to Console Application. Even if you have a GUI this will launch the console window in the background for debug use etc.

Comment: Thats a start, but now it pops up a console window that I don't really need.  Previously I could see Console.Writeline output in the "Output" box in VS.  Reenabling that would be ideal.

Comment: What about using Debug.WriteLine instead of Console?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you need is to change all of your [`Console.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.writeline.aspx) calls to be [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline.aspx), if what you want is to see the values in the Visual Studio Output window.